# Upper and lower bounds for a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices

Let us say that we know the following things about an $n\times n$ matrix $A$:

- $A$ is symmetric and strictly positive definite.
- For some particular vector $v$, we have $\lambda |v| \leq |Av|\leq \Lambda |v|$. (Here, $\Lambda > \lambda >0$.)
- For all vectors $w$ that are perpendicular to $v$, we have $\lambda |w|\leq |Aw| \leq \Lambda |w|$.

Can we conclude that $\lambda |e| \leq |Ae| \leq \Lambda |e|$ for all $e\in \mathbb R^n$? If not, can we say $m|e| \leq |Ae| \leq M |e|$ for some other constants depending on $\lambda$ and $\Lambda$? Such as $\lambda/2 |e| \leq |Ae| \leq 2\Lambda|e|$? This upper bound is obvious, but I am not sure about the lower bound.

Comment: You can always get the bound with $m = \min_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)} \lambda$ where $\sigma(A)$ is the collection of all eigenvalues of $A$. Do you want a bound $m$ that depends on $\lambda, \Lambda$?

Comment: @levap Yes, I've edited to clarify.

Comment: Your question is related to what is called a "Rayleigh quotient".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No such luck.  Consider
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&\epsilon}
$$
for (a small value of) $\epsilon > 0$. For $v = (1,1)$, we have $\frac 1{\sqrt{2}} \|v\| < \|Av\| < \|v\|$.  This similarly holds for the vectors perpendicular to $v$, which are parallel to $(-1,1)$.  However, $\min_{e \in \Bbb R^2} \frac{|Ae|}{|e|} = \epsilon$.

So, our actual lower bound could be arbitrarily close to $0$.

Comment: Right you are. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: On the other hand, if we tweak your idea slightly, we end up with the [min-max theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem)